# What is the URL for access Ad Set Delivery Estimate endpoint?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I know that [Ad Account Reachestimate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/reachestimate/v2.8) was deprecated, but now available new endpoint [Ad Set Delivery Estimate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/delivery_estimate/). I can't find any URLs in the documentation for this endpoint. Can you specify the URL to access this endpoint, please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/delivery_estimate/

Curl example:

```
curl -G \
--data-urlencode 'targeting_spec={ 
"geo_locations": {"country_groups":["worldwide"]}, 
"user_device": ["Galaxy S6","One m9"], 
"user_os": ["android"] 
}' \
-d 'optimization_goal=IMPRESSIONS' \
-d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/delivery_estimate
```

Comment: Although it's in the documentation, I can't get it to work right now. Keep getting OAuthException "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (delivery_estimate) on node type (AdAccount)". Up until today you could query the adset at https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<Ad_SET_ID>/delivery_estimate but that also seems to be broken...

Comment: Works again now.